# Buffer size for reading a UTF-8-encoded file using ICU (ICU4C)

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, fstream, icu

I am trying to read a UTF-8-encoded file using ICU4C on Windows with msvc11. I need to determine the size of the buffer to build a UnicodeString. Since there is no fseek-like function in the ICU4C API I thought I could use an underlying C-file:

```
#include <unicode/ustdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*...*/
UFILE *in = u_fopen("utfICUfseek.txt", "r", NULL, "UTF-8");
FILE* inFile = u_fgetfile(in);
fseek(inFile,  0, SEEK_END); /* Access violation here */
int size = ftell(inFile);
auto uChArr = new UChar[size];
```

There are two problems with this code:

1. It "throws" access violation at the fseek() line for some reason (Unhandled exception at 0x000007FC5451AB00 (ntdll.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024.)
2. The size returned by the ftell function will not be the size I want because UTF-8 can use up to 4 bytes for a code point (a u8"tю" string will be of length 3).

So the questions are:

1. How do I determine a buffer size for a UnicodeString if I know that the input file is UTF-8-encoded?
2. Is there a *portable* way to use iostream/fstream for both reading and writing ICU's UnicodeStrings?

Edit:
Here is the possible solution (tested on msvc11 and gcc 4.8.1) based on the first answer and C++11 Standard. A few things from ISO IEC 14882 2011:

1. "The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A
   byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
   execution character set (2.3) **and the eight-bit code units of the
   Unicode UTF-8** encoding form..."
2. "The basic source character set consists of 96 characters...", - 7 bits needed already
3. "The basic execution character set and the basic execution
   wide-character set shall each contain all the members of the basic
   source character set..."
4. "Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to
   store any member of the implementation’s basic character set."

So, to make this portable for platforms where the implementation defined size of char is 1 byte = 8 bits (don't know where this isn't true) we can read Unicode characters into chars using unformatted input operation:

```
std::ifstream is;
is.open("utfICUfSeek.txt");
is.seekg(0, is.end);
int strSize = is.tellg();
auto inputCStr = new char[strSize + 1];
inputCStr[strSize] = '\0'; //add null-character at the end
is.seekg(0, is.beg);
is.read(inputCStr, strSize);
is.seekg(0, is.beg);
UnicodeString uStr = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(inputCStr);
is.close();
```

What troubles me is that I have to create an additional buffer for chars and only then convert them to the required UnicodeString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative to using ICU.

Using the standard `std::fstream` you can read the whole/ part of the file into a standard `std::string` then iterate over that with a unicode aware iterator. http://code.google.com/p/utf-iter/

```
std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.reserve(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        contents.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        in.close();
        return(contents);
    }
    throw(errno);
}
```

Then in your code

```
std::string myString = get_file_contents( "foobar" );
unicode::iterator< std::string, unicode::utf8 /* or utf16/32 */ > iter = myString.begin();

while ( iter != myString.end() )
{
    ...
    ++iter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The get_file_contents is what I was looking for, though I don't know if its faster to use the assign(...) function, which has a linear complexity (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign number (7)) or the read function given the tellg() result (see the edit). The iterator solution is interesting and I am going to explore sources but I might also need ICU's collation and locales so probably I can't abandon this library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *either* you want to read in the whole file at once for some kind of postprocessing, in which case `icu::UnicodeString` is not really the best container...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in( "utfICUfSeek.txt" );
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << in.rdbuf();
    in.close();
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

...or what you **really** want is to read into `icu::UnicodeString` just like into any other string object but went the long way around...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in( "utfICUfSeek.txt" );
    icu::UnicodeString uStr;
    in >> uStr;
    // ...
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

...or I am completely missing what your problem really is about. ;)

Comment: This is really outdated as of now. I guess tried to avoid creating a separate buffer for chars because you end up having a UTF-8 string (in this char array) and a UTF-16 string (internally in a UnicodeString) in RAM. So a solution would be to implement a function which would read UTF-8 code units and deduce code points (out of these code units) one by one. Then it would convert a set of UTF-8 code units (which form a valid code point) to UTF-16 code units and 'load' them into a UnicodeString and after that try to deduce a next set of code units enough to form a code point and so on.

Comment: The latter suggestion only requires up to 4 bytes for UTF-8 code units in RAM and a maximum of TotalCodePoints * 4 bytes for UTF-16 buffer. But then you have to load a UChar (just a typedef for 16-bit integer) buffer into a UnicodeString without copying UTF-16 string (this http://tinyurl.com/o2hxfd3
 would have been appropriate if it released the buffer after the string is deleted).